What are the hostnames that Apple products contact for location services?
I need to give location access to some apps on macOS and iOS so they can scan wireless networks, that's a thing now. I do not want system services or other apps to make location queries to Apple's location servers though, if these apps I'm setting up query their own servers (assuming Apple even allows devs to do that to begin with) so be it, but not Apple's.
I've seen these hostname in Little Snitch alerts before, I think it's just one, it's something with the DNS labels "gss" and "loc" in it but I can't remember nor I've been able to find it in the logs. Maybe it was just on s i.e. "gs". Also I'm not sure if they were two labels or one with those two "words" strings a hyphen.
I did find the dying gasp-like-function hostname for Find My Enterprise devices and plus a list of the services/hosts used for MDM (under which my devices are) but this, general/generic location thing, is on the consumer side service. In a way I can see why Apple wouldn't list in for the network admins.
Anyway, I'd appreciate anything you have. Anything is good — except a wildcard hostname, but thankfully it's not. :)
